# How to filter dropdown option in Struts JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts

```
<html-el:select property="someType" size="1" styleClass="someClass">
    <c:forEach var="someType" items="${LOV.IOP_SomeType}">
        <html-el:option value="$someType.key">
            <c:out value="${someType.value}">
        </html-el:option>
    </c:forEach?
</html-el:select>
```

From the above code, I'll have a full item list for `someType`. Now I'm wondering how to modify so that it only display when `value == "testing"`

Comment: Personally I don't think this is best handled in the view layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<c:if>` tag, and put that comparison:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm